# How to find out if Windows Sockets send buffer is empty?

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock

I need to know when a Windows socket's send buffer is empty, that is, at what time it has been put onto the wire. SIO_FLUSH seems to do nothing but kill the contents of this buffer instead of wait until TCP is done sending it.

The reason I need it is because I must not start sending data on a separate connection until the data on the connection at hand is all sent (or closest to that).

This may seem like a very strange requirement that reeks like bad protocols, but the protocol is HTTP and this has been put through it's paces :). I require pushing large amounts of data to a browser in real time, and the network lag time prevents me from requesting more data when data has come in as this would make requests slower based on lag as opposed to just bandwidth. The ideal solution would be an endless request that receives 1 real-time data stream, but as stated, I must use HTTP which doesn't support this. I have no control over the HTTP implementation on the client side (strictly request-response).

So, to optimize bandwidth usage and to get as close to real-time data as possible, I need to know when the buffer on connection 1 is sent before I send connection 2's data (data is generated in real time and should not be stale).

If anyone has any idea how to accomplish this, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, there is no way to query the status of the send buffer.

If the sender uses a blocking socket, the socket will keep accepting more data as long as the send buffer has room, and then when the buffer fills up the socket will block the sending code until the buffer frees up some room.

If the sender uses a non-blocking socket instead, the socket will report a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error when the buffer fills up, and then a later `FD_WRITE` notification will tell the sender when the send buffer has freed up some room.

Either way, the socket informs you what it going on, you don't have to query for it.

Depending on the nature of your response data, Either the HTTP 1.1 `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` feature, or various [server pushing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_push) techniqus, can be used in HTTP for the type of situation you describe.  Whether or not your HTTP client supports any of them is a separate matter.

Comment: The client is any browser. I need to send highly time-sensitive data to the browser with max bandwidth utilization. How would xmlHttpRequest split up the chunks? Worth looking in to! In any case, I found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214397 which describes setting the sendbuffer size to 0, which may do what I need it to do, except I'll probably need to wait for the TCP ACK from the browser (wasted bandwidth, as I could be sending the next batch).

Comment: xmlHttpRequest operates on a separate connection, and simply sends a command and receives a response like any other normal HTTP operation.  You cannot detect or catch TCP ACKs directly, WinSock handles them internally and then either unblocks a blocked `send()` or sends a `FD_WRITE` notification as needed. Personally, I wouldn't even try to throttle the bandwidth at all, just send as much data as you can as fast as you can, and pay attention to when the socket tells you when it can and cannot accept more data.  That is all you need to do.

Comment: The reason I'd be waiting for the ACK is because without a send buffer, the OS has no other way to hang on to the data until it has been ack'd than to block my send. If the packet gets lost it needs to be resent, so the OS needs to have the data until then. Instead of allowing the app to continue, it has no choice but to block it until the ack is in.
For my purposes, I require the responses to arrive in-order on the client, which means I can't just answer when I want to. Also, request A should be sent as fast as possible and I don't want B to interfere with that (as they would share bandwidth)

Comment: HTTP uses a command/response model. You cannot send a new HTTP request on a connection until a response to a previous HTTP request on the same connection has been received first (unless you use piplining, which is an advanced technique). So I am still lost as to what you are trying to accomplish. I think you are confused about how sockets really work in app code, and are expecting to do things in app code that the OS handles instead. You do not handle ACKs yourself. You send a request, keep reading until the response is finished, send the next request, and so on.