# Delphi Winsock2 - send to different ports - packet between stream

Tags: delphi, networking, winsock2

On Windows 10, I open two ports on one remote host in my lan, 50100 and 50101 in this case. This is a custom protocol.

Now I send with WSASend and overlappend one time about 1MByte to port 50101 and 1 small packet to port 50100.

What I am experiencing is, that, because the data to 50101 is too big for one frame, sliding window is used and in between this stream, the packet to 50100 is sent.

[image]

Why is that so? Why does Windows not finish the data transfer to 50101 and sends data for 50100 in between?

Shortened Code:

```
// Socket creation for both sockets
Dest.sin_family       := AF_Inet;
Dest.sin_addr.S_Addr  := inet_addr(FHostAddr);
// Rest of Dest is initialized with 0
F5010XSocket := WSASocket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP,nil,0,WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);    
Winsock2.bind(F5010XSocket,SockAddr(dest),sizeof(dest));
Dest.sin_port    := htons(FDestPort); // 50100 or 50101
Winsock2.connect(FSocket,SockAddr(Dest),sizeof(Dest));
```

The send routine looks like this:

```
// Send data to port 50101
// WSABuff.len is about an MByte
WSASend(F50101Socket,@WSABuff50101,1,WSABuff50101.len,0,@Overlapped50101,nil);
if not WSAGetOverlappedResult(F50101Socket, @Overlapped50101, SentBytes, TRUE, Flags) then
// Some logging
// SentBytes looks correct at this point, wireshark shows that this routine finishes right after 
// it was called and data transfer is still ongoing, as defined in the msdn
WSASend(F50100Socket,@WSABuff50100,1,WSABuff50100.len,0,@Overlapped50100,nil);
// Returns and the data is send somewhere between the stream to port 50101
```

This question is not about the communication behaviour. It can be solved if the server sends a "Data received" message for port 50101 and i programmatically wait for that message, but it would be nice if I could wait for the transmission finish on my client without any messages from the server, before sending data to port 50100.

Or is there a way to detect if data was physically sent?

Comment: You would need to check if the send buffer is empty, but it seems like [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249065/how-to-find-out-if-windows-sockets-send-buffer-is-empty).

Comment: There is no guarantee of packet ordering across the internet - TCP/IP will fix up the order on the client side for a given connection but certainly not between connections (IP:PORT). Even if you send the packets in the exact order you wanted there is no guarantee they arrive at the other end in that order.

Comment: *Why is that so? Why does Windows not finish the data transfer to 50101 and sends data for 50100 in between?* In addition to what @Olivier said: you have two different "channels" open: `host:50101` and `host:50100`. If one could lock out the other one, it would be quite disastrous. Imagine a situation where you are uploading a 6 GB video to a host, but would not be able to simultaneously look at a directory listing at the same host just because your request would wait for the upload to conclude.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Ok, seems I am assuming the wrong things. So the Winsock Functions are not executed in the same thread? Can I assume that there is its own message loop running which gets the "SendData" command via the Winsock API?
I am searching for information what happens after, for example, i call wsasend, but couldn't find something about it.

Comment: When `WSASend()` returns, data have been written to the send buffer. That's all. The actual emission will be done later by the network layer in the background.

Comment: "*is there a way to detect if data was physically sent?*" - Once your app gives data to the socket, it is placed in the socket's outbound buffer, and it is out of your hands. The kernel will transmit the buffer contents on its own time. The only way to detect that physical transmission is to monitor the network hardware, such as with a pcap library. But that will only tell you when the data goes out, not when it arrives at the destination (unless you also monitor the ACKs coming back), but even then, the data could be sitting in the target's own buffer and not read by the receiving app yet.